# Samba installation failed on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: package-management, samba

I was trying to install samba to access shared printer on windows pc connected via office network, following response came out from terminal. please guide me how to install Samba or any other alternative.

---

```
crm@crm-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install samba
[sudo] password for crm: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 samba : Depends: samba-common (= 2:3.6.6-3ubuntu4) but 2:3.6.6-3ubuntu5 is to be installed
         Depends: libwbclient0 (= 2:3.6.6-3ubuntu4) but 2:3.6.6-3ubuntu5 is to be installed
         Recommends: tdb-tools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
crm@crm-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~$
```

Comment: What happens when you enter `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install samba`?

Comment: Please see sudo apt-get update response.

Comment: I deleted the output of the update. Because it looks like it simply worked for you. However according to http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/samba the needed packages have changed. So at the moment you should be able to install the package as you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
sudo apt-get install --fix-broken && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install samba
```

> **If it doesn't succeed** , then remove those particular packages which dependencies were unmet :

```
sudo apt-get remove samba-common libwbclient0 tdb-tools
```

> **If it doesn't succeed, then you have to do some manual operation.**

`samba-common (= 2:3.6.6-3ubuntu4)` does not exist on the Official Ubuntu [repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=quantal&searchon=names&keywords=samba-common) for Ubuntu 12.10. you could have used a Old repository that containing `samba-common (= 2:3.6.6-3ubuntu4)`

So you have to find that repository by

```
apt-cache policy samba-common
```

In the results, firstly mentioned PPA is the one that causing problems.

You need to find weather it is a Worth repository or Useless. That means weather it has installed a Important Package that you have installed. For that, run :

```
aptitude search "?origin <ppa name> ?installed"
```

** Replace `<ppa name>` with Name of the PPA (Omitting `ppa:`)

This will list the packages which have been installed from that PPA.

> **Then, If it is a worth repository that containing other Important package, You have to do
>   [pinning](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto).**

For that run:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/preferences
```

Add following lines to the file and Save.

```
Package: samba-common
Pin: release o=Ubuntu
Pin-Priority: 200 

Package: samba-common
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-<ppa name>
Pin-Priority: 100
```

** Replace `<ppa name>` with name Of the PPA (Omitting `ppa:`)

Then, Try to install again.

> **If it is a Useless PPA, remove the PPA and then update.**

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove <PPA Name> && sudo apt-get update
```

Then try to install.

Answer (score 0):

The package that owns /etc/samba/smb.conf is

```
samba-common
```

You should be able to copy the config from /usr/share/samba/smb.conf if /etc/samba/smb.conf is missing & then run

```
sudo dpkg --configure samba-common
```