# Problem in upgrading : linux-header package 3.2.0.56 generic -pae : unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, dependencies

I tried upgrading multiple times , tried removing dependecies and also tried removing old kernels but it keeps on crashing saying no space in disk. I keep checking it says I have 1.1 GB free but it keeps crashing I can mount more than 1 drive now and it keeps adding more and more problems.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

linux-headers-generic-pae: Depends: linux-headers-3.2.0-56-generic-pae but it is not installed
```

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: What is the output of `sudo apt-get check`?

Answer (score 11):

Try with following command:

```
sudo apt-get install --fix-broken && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get update
```

Then update again.

If it is doesn't succeed then follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/379757/164718) answer.